# Javascript event e.which?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

What is the functionality of Javascript event `e.which`? Please brief with example.

Comment: Two years later, I was having trouble understanding this property after reading several pages elsewhere. Then I stumbled across this old post and got it. So to @Reigel, maybe reconsider before telling someone to Google something. Maybe they already did. That is not SO's purpose.

Comment: @Aerovistae, on that time, searching google would give you something like http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html ... which is very helpful already...

Comment: Tim Down's answer is so much superior than the accepted answer at the moment.

Comment: @JuanMendes - Googling "javascript event.which" got me here as the first result. Is that something you feel is "undesireable"? I mean, it sounds like you would rather that the question was never asked/answered here.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

### Deprecation notice (as of September 2020)

[KeyboardEvent.which](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) has been deprecated. Please look for alternatives, such as [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key). Read the full API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent).

`e.which` is not an event, `which` is a property of the `event` object, which most people label as `e` in their event handlers. It contains the key code of the key which was pressed to trigger the event (eg: keydown, keyup).

```
document.onkeypress = function(myEvent) { // doesn't have to be "e"
    console.log(myEvent.which);
};
```

With that code, the console will print out the code of any key you press on the keyboard.

Comment: It does not really require Firebug, only some sort of console.log (which many more than Firebug provides, for example the webkitt-ens).

Comment: `which` also exists on mouse events, and your example won't work on IE, in which an event handler does not receive an event parameter.

Comment: Just another note of help for all who find this (will post on other e.which questions prolly too). I made a post at jQuery forums that list a good majority of e.which codes and their associated keys. The post is here -> http://forum.jquery.com/topic/eventwhich-code-list-just-for-help

Comment: [KeyboardEvent.which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) has been deprecated. Please look for the alternatives, such as [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key). See more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent).

Answer (score 83):

`which` is a property of `Event` objects. It is defined for key-related and mouse-related events in most browsers, but in both cases is not defined in IE (prior to version 9).

For mouse-related events, `which` specifies the mouse button that was involved. For IE < 9, the equivalent value is found in `window.event.button`. Just to complicate things, non-IE browsers also support a `button` property of mouse events that sometimes reports a different value from `which`. Also, browsers sometimes have different values for the same button or combination of buttons. If you stick to using `which` in all browsers that support it and `button` in IE < 9, the one constant is that a value of 1 always means the left mouse button was involved (though not necessarily alone).

```
document.onmousedown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var button = (typeof e.which != "undefined") ? e.which : e.button;
    if (button == 1) {
        alert("Left mouse button down");
    }
};
```

For a full analysis, I recommend [Jan Wolter's article on JavaScript mouse events](http://unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html).

For key-related events, `which` relates to the key that has been pressed. For `keydown` and `keyup` events, this is relatively simple: it's the key code for the key pressed, and  returns the same value as the event's `keyCode` property. Since all browsers support the `keyCode` property and IE < 9 does not support `which`, you should generally use `keyCode` for `keydown` and `keyup` events.

For `keypress` events, the situation is more complicated. For printable character keys, `which` is the character code for the key pressed and is supported in more browsers than the `charCode` property. In IE < 9 the equivalent is again the `keyCode` property. So for detecting the character typed, the following is a cross-browser approach. Be aware that the code below should not be used for non-printable keys such as arrow keys, which you should instead detect in the `keydown` event:

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (charCode) {
        alert("Character typed: " + String.fromCharCode(charCode));
    }
};
```

Again, for more details I recommend [Jan Wolter's article on JavaScript key events](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)

Comment: @Toskan: The accepted answer was posted a few hours before mine, and may have been accepted before I posted mine.

Comment: OP let _Tim down_ by not accepting this as answer! :)

Answer (score 12):

This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.

You should use `KeyboardEvent.key` instead, if it's available.

http://codepen.io/KevinOrfas/pen/QKbKAd

Comment: `KeyboardEvent.key` will return **"the identifier of the key (char)"** while `KeyboardEvent.which` will return **"the numeric keyCode"**.

Comment: Note that [IE11 and Edge18 don't consistently implement the spec](https://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key).

Answer (score 7):

During an event, `e`:

```
e.which
```

is same as:

```
e.keyCode
```

So both functions allow you to obtain the keycode of the key pressed during a keypress, keydown or keyup event

Many people use `||` (OR)  to make sure their code works in browsers which don't support which property. Look at the code below:

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
   var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
   alert(key);
}
```