# How to submit a form when pressing Enter in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get the form submitted by pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> in the `<textarea>` instead of pressing the `<input type="submit">` button?

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>
        <FORM ACTION="MyInserts.php"  METHOD="GET">
            firstname:  <TEXTAREA NAME="firstbox"></TEXTAREA><BR>
            <INPUT TYPE="submit" Value="send">
        </FORM>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You need to learn magic tricks to accomplish that..AND BTW USE lowercase FOR MARKUP, and `ENTER` will probably work here, you don't need to use any special javascript for that

Comment: What are you talking about? do you have some code to give this question context?

Comment: Welcome to SO, you really need to improve this question. Have a look at the faq http://stackoverflow.com/faq .

Comment: You mean **Press** Enter instead of **Clicking** on a "Send Button" ?

Comment: sorry guys, am new on stack overflow

Comment: Are you actually using PHP or did you just tag it with that? Just curious.

Comment: @War10ck `action=MyInserts.php`

Comment: @Mr.Alien True good point. Sorry that was a dumb question.

Comment: and btw you are using camel case for naming pages, just if you don't know, page names on linux are case sensitive

Comment: i just tagged it with that, i dont have to paste the entire code, this is like a shorten code

Comment: @Mr.Alien The names are actually Pascal case. Camel case would start with a lowercase letter and uppercase every word after that. Pascal is uppercase letter on every word including the first.

Comment: @War10ck Oh yea, I just missed the capital `M` ;)

Comment: @Mr.Alien no worries chief. All good. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to submit a `<form>` whenever the user presses <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on a `<textarea>`, you should be assigning a `onKeyDown` event handler to it, and submit the form manually with javascript when you detect it was <kbd>ENTER</kbd> that was pressed:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function pressed(e) {
            // Has the enter key been pressed?
            if ( (window.event ? event.keyCode : e.which) == 13) { 
                // If it has been so, manually submit the <form>
                document.forms[0].submit();
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="MyInserts.php">
        <textarea onkeydown="pressed(event)"></textarea>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

See it working in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uYSSL/).

Comment: @KelvinBala there's a button named `edit` below your question. If your comment was meant to tell us that this is the code you've got, please  use it to edit it in.

Comment: @KelvinBala: and there's an XSS attack possible with your code, you should use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) when printing `$_GET["ident"]` to avoid that.

Comment: Sorry to comment on a four month old post, but could you explain `(window.event ? event.keyCode : e.which)` and what each part means? Why can't I just use `e.which`?

Comment: @user1755043 Some browsers (such as IE < 9) don't support `e.which`. And other browsers don't seem to support `window.event.keyCode`. See Tim Down's answer to [javascript event e.which?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3050984/851811) for more context.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading this question post-2020 like me and trying to use it with TypeScript, you probably know that TypeScript will tell you that `e.keyCode` or `e.which` is **deprecated**!

So instead you can use `e.key` which will give you the exact string of the key that is being pressed like it will give you `Enter` for pressing the enter button or it will give you `ctrl` for pressing the control btn, so hopefully you get the idea!

Also if you want to write a function to convert it to the old way of getting the key code you can use something like :

```js
switch (theChar) {
    case "Backspace":
      return 8;
    case "Tab":
      return 9;
    case "Enter":
      return 13;
    case "Alt":
      return 18;
    case "Escape":
      return 27;
    case "Delete":
      return 127;
    case "Minus":
      return 45;
    case "Plus":
      return 43;
    case "Equal":
      return 61;
    case "Delete":
      return 127;
    case "BracketRight":
      return 93;
    case "BracketLeft":
      return 91;
    case "Backslash":
      return 92;
    case "Slash":
      return 47;
    case "Semicolon":
      return 59;
    case "Colon":
      return 58;
    case "Comma":
      return 44;
    case "Period":
      return 46;
    case "Space":
      return 32;
    case "Quote":
      return 34;
    case "Backquote":
      return 39;

    //there are also "Numpad....." variants

    case "Unidentified":
      alert("handle the 'Unidentified' if you want to!");
  }
```

There are many other possible character values [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code/code_values)
but, AFAIK, there are no Unicode code points for them, such as:

```js
switch (theKey) {
    case "AltLeft":
    case "CapsLock":
    case "ControlRight":
    case "Fn":
    case "NumpadDecimal":
    ...
```

`event.which` may output some number for them, but it is not consistent across browsers/machines and they may overlap with other code points.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way to override the Enter key to submit from `textarea` now is to add an event listener to the textarea element and use `event.key` as @amdev suggested

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
  if (event.key == 'Enter') {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.forms[0].submit();
  }
});
```

You'll also want to prevent the default key action or you will include the line return in the submitted data