# stopping a jquery slider by pressing a key

Tags: jquery

I found this code sample and I am trying to figure out how to make the slider stop by pressing a key on the keyboard, but I have no clue how to do it.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  
 var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
 var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
 var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
 var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
 
 $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
 
 $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });
 
    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600); 

html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #58DDAF;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Incredibly Basic Slider</h1>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

I have tried searching the net for similar examples with this functionality (stopping by pressing a key) where I can get an idea on how to do it, but with no success.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [Look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050984/javascript-event-e-which)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear interval on keyup

```
var runSlider = setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
}, 3000);

$(window).on('keyup', function(){
    clearInterval(runSlider)
})
```

If you want stop slider only after pressing specific key, you need key code (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/) and if statement

```
$(window).on('keyup', function(){
    if(e.which === 32){ // 32 - space
        clearInterval(runSlider)
    }
})
```

**Full code below:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var runSlider = setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);
    
    $(window).on('keyup', function(){
        clearInterval(runSlider)
    })

  
 var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
 var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
 var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
 var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
 
 $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
 
 $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });
 
    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600); 

html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #58DDAF;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Incredibly Basic Slider</h1>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

Comment: That did it.... Amazing. Any idea how to make it start with a key as well? I have tried with      $(window).on('keydown', function(){
        moveRight();
    }) but that just starts the next slide and stops then

Comment: I have tried that, but once I stop it... it doesnt start... I user this code:    $(window).on('keyup', function(){
    clearInterval(runSlider)
})
 $(window).on('keyup', function(){
    setInterval(runSlider)
})

Comment: you have 2 event listener's, and they waiting for same event, So they both starting own functions [clearInterval(runSlider) and startInterval(runSlider)]. You need something like var isRunning = true and change it in them. With if(isRunning) you can do them both in one function.  var isRunning = true; if(isRunning){isRunning = false} https://jsfiddle.net/und3rdg/d8x1pkz6/

Comment: tried like this https://jsfiddle.net/ty8ogqj5/ but didnt work. Any idea?

Comment: Nope, it has the same behavior... stopping it but doesn't start again.

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you soo much. I will study the code to see how it is done.