# Javascript check to see if input is in english or arabic

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make an HTML page (that is simply a form) that accepts both English and Arabic inputs.
For example:
First Name and Last Name: (Have to be in English)
Full name in Arabic: (Has to be in Arabic)
I tried playing around by using the following code:

```
function isArabic(text) {
var pattern = /[\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F]/;
result = pattern.test(text);
return result;
}
```

But I'm not experienced in javascript and am having a hard time getting it to work and linking it properly in the html

**This is a sample of the HTML:**

```
 <form name="taskForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <b>First Name: </b>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" max="15" required>
    <br><br>
    <b>Last name: </b>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" max="15" required>
    <br><br>
    <b>Name in Arabic: </b>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="arName" max="100"> 
    <br><br>
    <b>Gender: </b>
    <br><input type="radio" name="Gender" value="male" required>  Male
    <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="female" required>  Female
    <br><br>
    <b>Salary: </b>
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="salary" step="0.001" min="0">
    <br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: What are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: Your pattern says "must have at least one Arabic letter". Is that what you want? Do you want "all characters must be Arabic letters"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the piece of code that I finally used to make it work!
All credits go to: https://stackoverflow.com/cv/leniel with his article: https://www.leniel.net/2012/10/javascript-regex-jquery-to-match-only-english-characters-in-input-textbox.html

I was able to use his code which took only English and simply changed the Unicode values to those of the Arabic letters:

```
$("#arabicCheck").on("keypress", function (event) {
 var arabicAlphabetDigits = /[\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufc3f]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]|[\u0200]|[\u00A0]/g;

/* Retrieving the key from the char code passed in event.which
 For more info on even.which, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3050984/114029
var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which); */

if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || arabicAlphabetDigits.test(key)) {
  return true;
}
  return false;
});

$('#arabicCheck').on("paste", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

This is how it looked like in the HTML section:

```
<b>Name in Arabic: </b><br>
   <input id="arabicCheck" type="text" name="arName" max="100" >
   <br><br>
```

Answer (score 3):

Inputs have a `pattern` attribute where you can put your regex. No JS required.

```
<input type="text" name="arName" pattern="[\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F]">
```

Comment: But if you want to use JS: Your script seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/akf0g2dx/2/ The error seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I did want to use only javascript instead of a pattern. Also, when I used your pattern it did not work for some reason.

Comment: Rats. I didn't test it, it's your pattern 

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

```js
var string = 'عربية‎';

alert(isArabic(string));


function isArabic(text) {
var arabic = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;
result = arabic.test(text);
return result;
}
```