# How String.fromCharCode function work for mobile key board in html input field

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, vue.js

I want to capture the keyboard key code and convert it to characters. I am using the String.fromCharCode javascript function but it only works on a computer keyboard it is not working with a mobile keypad. Any help will be appreciated.

```
$(".inputsmeter").keyup(function (e) { 
  let key = e.which; 
  let c = String.fromCharCode(key); 
  alert(c); 
});
```

Comment: Please take care to format your questions properly. Before I edited it, this was in 20px+ text with no code formatting.

Comment: `which` has been deprecated for quite a while, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3051017/1427878

Answer (score 0):

```js
const inputElem = document.getElementById('input')
inputElem.addEventListener('input', (ev) => { 
  console.log(ev);
  alert(`e.data: ${ev.data}`);
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="type something... " />
```

This runs as expected on my iOS Safari 15.
Type `a` in the input will see an alert printing:

```
ev.data: a
```

Comment: The same problem is on Samsung mobile , the browser chrome it shows different characters in the alert.
in a laptop t works okay but not on mobile.

Comment: I just want some script for OTP code which runs works for both laptops and mobile and the keys like backspace and when entering a character jumps to following input also replace of existing input work when clicking on already filled information in puts.

Comment: Replaced `keyup` with `input` which should work on Android