# jQuery Drag and Follow Mouse

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a two-column slideable region with a drag-bar in the center, see this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W7tGj/2/

I'm trying to avoid adding jQ-UI to the mix, so any help would be appreciated. I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Comment: I kinda got it working...it works if you move the mouse really slowly while dragging.

http://jsfiddle.net/W7tGj/2/

Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572483/jquery-mousedown-mousemove

Comment: jQ UI is probably the best way to go. There are some other plugins out there that do what you want.  i.e. http://www.methvin.com/splitter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First :
 - add container div to check mousemove

```
<div id="content-div">
  <div id="left-panel">f</div>

  <div id="drag-bar">f</div>

  <div id="right-panel">f</div>
</div>
```

Second :
 - add mousemove event into div container

```
var movebar = false; 

$('#drag-bar').mousedown(function(e){
    movebar = true;
});

$('#drag-bar').mouseup(function(e){
    movebar = false;
});

$('#content-div').mousemove(function(e){
    if(movebar)
    {
        var x = e.pageX;
        $('#left-panel').css({'width': x+'px'});
        $('#right-panel').css({'margin-left': (x+5)+'px'});
    }
});
```

Comment: I had tried something similar (detecting mouseup/down and setting a var) but missed isolating it to the container. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try it this way, http://jsfiddle.net/W7tGj/6/, although it still cannot support drag, it does do the right thing when mouse is down