# Holding a mouse on enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've got this JS program:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avgQVa

```
$('.divider').draggable({
  axis: 'x',
  drag: function(e, ui) {
    $('.right').width(100 - ui.position.left);
    $('.yellow').css('right', ui.position.left);
  }
});
```

I can reveal red rect by moving the grey divider to the right, but I need this divider to follow my mouse whenever I enter this block. How do I do this?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/12152244/631652

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Handle the mouse move event on the parent div
$( "div:first" ).mousemove(function(e) {
  // calculate the mouse position relative to the div element position on the page
  var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;  
  $('.divider').css('left', x);
  $('.left').css('width', x);
});
```

In order for it to work, I had to tweak the CSS too:

```
.left {
  left: 0px;
 /* This makes the left div render "above" the others, so when we change its width it shows up */
  z-index: 1; 
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epwQLr

Comment: just slightly faster than me. Works here

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exatcly what I need - content inside yellow rect should stay still.